# Autocmd on directory to replace netrw

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, netrw, filetype

I use [the ranger plugin](https://github.com/francoiscabrol/ranger.vim) wich I can trigger with a shortcut. But when I open a directory I would like to use the plugin instead of netrw.
So I have found that the filetype of directories is `netrw`, using `set filetype`on a directory, and decided to put an autocommand in my vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType netrw :Ranger<CR>
```

But it doesn't work. I can't find anything on the web on autocmds on directory.
Anyone has an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a look at [how](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish/blob/4ae4303748221543aaa37030f209da11de817270/plugin/dirvish.vim#L8-L20) `Dirvish` did it, and tested this:

```
augroup ranger
    au!
    au VimEnter * sil! au! FileExplorer *
    au BufEnter * if s:isdir(expand('%')) | bd | exe 'Ranger' | endif
augroup END

fu! s:isdir(dir) abort
    return !empty(a:dir) && (isdirectory(a:dir) ||
                \ (!empty($SYSTEMDRIVE) && isdirectory('/'.tolower($SYSTEMDRIVE[0]).a:dir)))
endfu
```

It seems to work but I don't know how reliable it is.

`s:isdir()` is a function which tests whether the path of the current buffer matches a directory.
The `VimEnter` autocmd seems to get rid of `netrw`.
The `BufEnter` autocmd deletes the buffer (if you want to wipe it completely, replace `bd` with `bw`), then calls the `ranger` file manager.

In the `Dirvish` plugin, before calling the `:Dirvish` command, the `BufEnter` autocmd redraws the screen and echo an empty string (`redraw | echo ''`). I don't know why it does this, so I didn't copied it, but if you have some issue (maybe with rendering artifacts, sometimes `:redraw!` is used to get rid of them), try to add these commands back:

```
au BufEnter * if s:isdir(expand('%'))
                  \| bd | redraw | echo '' | exe 'Ranger' | endif
```

Answer (score 2):

The [vim-ranger](https://github.com/Mizuchi/vim-ranger) plugin provides a similar integration with [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger), and accomplishes this out of the box. You can [look at the code](https://github.com/Mizuchi/vim-ranger/blob/master/plugin/ranger.vim#L53) to see how it does that if you're interesting in duplicating this behavior with the other plugin.

---

*Update*: I realized that disabling netrw as vim-ranger plugin disables `gx` to view files (I hadn't realized that this was part of netrw).

As a result, I've gone back to using [ranger.vim](https://github.com/francoiscabrol/ranger.vim) with the above accepted answer solution (the `Dirvish` mimicry) to auto open directories with ranger. This keeps the useful netrw functionality intact and seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

- Vim's default file explorer, the one you get when you do `$ vim .`, is Netrw. See `:help netrw`.
- Netrw is written as a plugin but it is very tightly integrated into Vim. Forcing another plugin in place of netrw won't be as simple as an autocommand. If you are curious you can take a look at how some popular alternative file explorers do that: [Dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish/blob/4ae4303748221543aaa37030f209da11de817270/plugin/dirvish.vim#L15) and [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/f26eaf83551631e683e339f00e2c97bd6e8356d7/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L168).

As a very lightweight alternative, you could create a simple alias:

```
$ alias vim.='vim +Ranger'
```

which allows you to do:

```
$ vim.
$ vim. path/to/some/dir
```

But at this point… why not simply press `E` in ranger?

Comment: Vim-ranger is a plugin than can open ranger within vim (maybe it's neovim only, I'm not sure wether thin can open terminal session), as a replacement of `netrw`. I just run the command `:Ranger`. I just want to make it so that the `Ranger` command would run when I accendentally open a directory instead of using `:Ranger`, insted of opening `netrw`. There's a trick from the NERDToggle github to launch it when passing a directory from a command line, but that's just one case...

Comment: Yes I know what vim-ranger is.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling netrw is easy: put `let g:loaded_netrw= 1`  and `let g:netrw_loaded_netrwPlugin= 1` into your .vimrc.  That way netrw won't be loaded, none of its maps installed, etc.